Problems registering inputs
Im trying to make a simple 2D game in Unity 6.
I made an empty gameobject and gave it a rigidbody 2D and a script for movement.
The script is supposed to move the player upwards if he presses space.It was working but it doesnt anymore.
Its removed now but earlier i tried adding an if check in the update method to check if any button is registering. What happend was when i pressed space or any other key neither of the debug.logs would show my message. Suddenly it worked when i spammed space followed by many other buttons. also the inputs would register several hundreds per sec the button was pressed. Thats why i added a cooldown which worked, but i still had to spam to get anything to happen. So i would think its an issue regarding input registering.
Here is the script for player movement (jumping):
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Blorb_movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;
   [SerializeField] private float flapStrength;
    private bool canFlap = true; // Variable for cooldown

    void Start()
    {
   
    }


    void Update()
    {
  
        // Check if the space key is pressed and we can flap (cooldown = over)
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canFlap)
        {
            Debug.Log("space was pressed");
            myRigidBody.linearVelocity = Vector2.up * flapStrength;

            canFlap = false;

            // Starts cooldown of 0.3 sec 
            StartCoroutine(FlapCooldown());
        }

    }
    private IEnumerator FlapCooldown()
    {
        // wait in cooldown before flapping again
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        canFlap = true;
    }
}

I was expecting the player character to move upwards when i pressed space, but nothing happend. earlier i was using "velocity" but VS told me it was depreceated and that i should use linear velocity. I believe thats when the problems started.

Beginning to be fed up of staging when you point for improvement and ask questions and no answers and its all most when pushed to main queue

linearVelocity is basically just the new name of velocity to be a bit more specific and aligned also with angularVelocity

Try debugging or Debug.Log to see if the input is actually not working or the issue is something else.
Here's a guide to debugging https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt2YdrUlzgg

It seems as if i solved it.
First i thought i had to press random buttons before pressing space for space to register. Later i found that the game worked if i clicked the game-window first. In the end what made it work was switching from playing in unfocused to focused. A little strange, but hey its working now
